# VueX actions/mutations error in Chrome console

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I try to store drawer data in VueX to use it on external component.

My console error: `[vuex] unknown action type: app/switchDrawer`

## My VueJS template:

*pages/test.vue*

```
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" app>
    <v-list dense>
      ...
    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    drawer: {
      get () {
        return this.$store.state.app.drawer
      },
      set (value) {
        console.log(value);
        return this.$store.dispatch('app/toggleDrawer', value)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The console.log() function give me lot of lines in loop in console.

I'd like to use too the mapGetters class from VueX instead computed get/set:

```
computed: mapGetters({
  drawer: 'app/drawer'
})
```

I've an error in console:

> [Vue warn]: Computed property "drawer" was assigned to but it has no
> setter.

## My VueX store:

*store/app.js*

```
export const state = () => ({
  drawer: true
})

export const getters = {
  drawer: state => state.drawer
}

export const mutations = {
  TOGGLE_DRAWER: (state) => {
    state.drawer = !state.drawer
  }
}

export const actions = {
  toggleDrawer ({ commit }, value) {
    commit('TOGGLE_DRAWER', value)
  }
}
```

Comment: Are your modules `namespaced`? If not then mapping works a bit diffrently `computed: { ...mapState({ drawer: state => state.FilenameOfYourModule.drawer })}`. The other issue might be the diffrent naming of your mutations and getters - I name them exactly the same -  but it's only a warning after all.

Comment: @Hexodus With this method, I get this error: `Computed property "drawer" was assigned to but it has no setter.`

Comment: Well my bad, it's not to be used for two way binding - have overlooked that you need a setter too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found your problem - a computed setter has to have no return statement.

```
 drawer: {
      get () {
        return this.$store.state.app.drawer
      },
      set (value) {
        this.$store.dispatch('app/toggleDrawer', value)
      }
    }
```

Please notice that your action submits a value to the mutation which dosen't take any value. So better add a new mutation that handles said value:

```
export const mutations = {
  SET_DRAWER: (state, value) => {
    state.drawer = value
  }
}

export const actions = {
  toggleDrawer ({ commit }, value) {
    commit('SET_DRAWER', value)
  }
}
```

Comment: With this code, I've a loop and I don't know why...

Comment: @pirmax I expanded my answer plz. take a look.

Answer (score 1):

IN CASE YOU DON'T WANT TO MAKE A NEW MUTATION AND HANDLE LOCALLY. (which I preferred personally as my store is pretty big already)

Faced similar issue using when using a vue-ui library(vuesax)

Solved it by initializing a new `data` variable to a `computed` variable (the one from the store) in created hook
([Why in `created` hook](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/computed-properties-in-data/11231/9))

```
   created() {
      this.localDrawer = this.drawer
   },
   data() {
      return {
         localDrawer: ''
      }
   },
   computed: {
      ...mapGetters({
         drawer: 'drawer'
      })
   },
   watch: {
      drawer(newValue, oldValue) {
         this.localDrawer = newValue
      }
   }
```

Now use `localDrawer` in the you app.
NOTE: I am watching the drawer variable as well. So that in any case if its value changes it gets reflected.